# Plotting histrogram with weighted bell curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm plotting a histogram with a bell curve and I'm running into problems with the bell curve part.  Basically, my data consists of 3 columns, an ITEM_TYPE, QTY, and WIDTH.  The data of my histogram needs to account for the quantity column, and I have no problem doing that, however, when I try to do the same for the bell curve, I'm not sure how to best go about it.  View my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('Size_Overview.csv')
df2 = df[df['ITEM_TYPE'] == 'Fixed Window']

weighted = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(df2['WIDTH'])
weighted.fit(fft=False, weights=df2['QTY_ORD'])

ax = plt.subplot()

ax.hist(df2['WIDTH'], bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], weights=df2['QTY_ORD'])

lnspc = np.linspace(0, 10, len(df2['WIDTH']))
m, s = stats.norm.fit(df2['WIDTH'], weights=df2['QTY_ORD'])
pdf_g = stats.norm.pdf(lnspc, m, s)  
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_g, label='Norm', c='red')

ax.set_ylabel('Unit Count (% of Total)')
ax.set_xlabel('Width (in Feet)')
ax.set_title('Width Distribution (Fixed Windows)')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 11, 1.0))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1.0))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

So basically, the "weights" argument in weighted.fit and ax.hist work perfectly, however, the same argument down in stats.norm.fit seems to be ignored completely.  So if I have 1 row in my data with a really high quantity, the histogram will make the proper adjustment but the bell curve stays exactly the same every time.  It's basically just calculating the mean and std of the WIDTH column completely ignoring the QTY

Here's what my chart looks like:

[image]

Here's what it looks like if I add a really large quantity to an item between 1 and 2 feet:

[image]

As you can see, the histogram adjusted correctly but the bell curve stayed roughly the same.  How can I make the bell curve adjust for my quantity column?  All tips are appreciated, thanks in advance

Edit: Looks like nobody could help, but I figured it out anyway.  Here's the workaround I came up with:

Added this code:

```
values = df2['WIDTH'].values
qty = df2['QTY_ORD'].astype(int)
count = qty.values
full_values = np.repeat(values, count)
```

and replaced:

```
m, s = stats.norm.fit(df2['WIDTH'], weights=df2['QTY_ORD'])
```

with:

```
m, s = stats.norm.fit(full_values)
```

So basically use the numpy repeat function to pass in the entire width column based on the number in the qty column.  That's it!!

So now my second chart looks like this:

[image]

Comment: if you don't get an answer to this post then consider using a *kde* plot from the `seaborn` package as described [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/distplot_options.html)

Comment: Thanks, actually solved my issue and already had looked at seaborn previously.  The weight argument was also an issue there I believe

Comment: *"... the same argument down in stats.norm.fit seems to be ignored completely."* Yes, it is ignored completely. That is a bug; the function should raise a TypeError when an invalid keyword parameter is used. It will be fixed before the next release of scipy.